# Django Search doesn't bring words with accents

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a simple search in my project, but my project is in Spanish , we have a lot of words with accents, and my search doesn't bring these words with accents.... is there any django /python function for this?

view.py

```
def search(request):
    categorias = Categoria.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True) # menu
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    result = []
    if query:
            results = Noticia.objects.filter(body__icontains=query)
    return render_to_response('buscar/search.html',{'query':query,'results': results,'categorias':categorias},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing to do with Django, but depends on the collation of your database tables. The collation is what determines how to sort and compare characters, and you need to choose one that compares accented and non-accented characters as equal. If you're using MySQL, a good collation would be `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Thanks guy's my collation is utf8_general_ci